# Debug files show up in Assets folder of production build

Tags: android, build, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have 3 build variants: `debug`, `development`, and `release`.

For `debug` and `development` there is a screen called `DebugActivity` and some debug stuff in the assets folder. Here is the directory structure:

```
main 
    AndroidManifest.xml  (no reference to DebugActivity)
    \java\com\companyname\android\DebugActivity.kt
    \assets\some debug things

debug 
    AndroidManifest.xml (DebugActivity defined)

development
    AndroidManifest.xml (DebugActivity defined)
```

- When I place the stuff from assets into main, I see these in the production build (when I open the APK with APKTool).
- When I copy-paste the \assets\some debug things into both `debug` and `development`, I don't see it in the production build, but I have double items, making it harder to maintain these files.

What is the correct way of structuring this? I would expect the build system to remove the reference to `DebugActivity` because I defined a boolean in my `build.gradle`.

**build.gradle:**

```
buildConfigField 'boolean', 'SHOW_DEBUG_MENU', 'false'
```

**MyApplication:**

```
open class MyApplication : DaggerApplication() {

    override fun applicationDidEnterForeground() {
        super.applicationDidEnterForeground()
        if (BuildConfig.SHOW_DEBUG_MENU) {
            DebugActivity.showNotification(this)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

when building, Gradle won't remove those files in assets folder, even if they're not used.

A good solution, without useless flags should be this one:

First thing to do is separate your flavors from Android's default buildTypes (debug/release), because they contain different flags in compile time and possibly different apk signatures. So it's best not to create any conflicts with the names.

Create a new dimension, which actually defines what is debug and what not. You could call it `environment` and the 2 dimensions will be `dev` and `prod`.

```
flavorDimensions "environment"
productFlavors {
dev {
  dimension "environment"
}

prod {
  dimension "environment"
}
```

Create 3 files:

**main\java\com\companyname\android\AbstractApplication.kt**

```
abstract class AbstractApplication: DaggerApplication() {
..
abstract fun initEnvApp()
fun onCreate() {
  ...
  initEnvApp()
  ...
}
```

**dev\java\com\companyname\android\MyApplication.kt**

```
abstract class MyApplication: AbstractApplication() {
..
fun initEnvApp() {
  \\init your debug logic
}
```

**prod\java\com\companyname\android\MyApplication.kt**

```
abstract class MyApplication: AbstractApplication() {
..
fun initEnvApp() {
  \\init your prod logic or leave it empty
}
```

Organize your files this way:

```
main 
    AndroidManifest.xml  (reference to DebugActivity, add this attribute to application tag: android:name="com.companyname.android.MyApplication")
    \java\com\companyname\android\AbstractApplication.kt

dev
    \java\com\companyname\android\MyApplication.kt
    \java\com\companyname\android\DebugActivity.kt
    \...all assets files

prod
    \java\com\companyname\android\MyApplication.kt
```

Build your APKs with

```
gradlew assembleDevDebug
gradlew assembleProdRelease
```

or any other combination you want.

If, apart from debug/not debug (which we called dev/prod), you need to split logic in another way, you can always create another environment (I'll call it `foo`), and after defining your productFlavors (let's say `foo1` and `foo2`) , you'll build in this way:

```
gradlew assembleDevFoo1Debug
gradlew assembleDevFoo2Debug
gradlew assembleProdFoo2Release
```

or any other combination you want

In both cases, builds which belong to DEV environment will contain your dev assets and classes, while any other PROD build won't.

Comment: It gives an error. Redeclaration: MyApplication class. Also, I'm not allowed to create build flavorDimensions. But it should also work without. But it doesn't.